# Is there some way to view the HTML part of an email in an external browser or as a PDF in notmuch?

Tags: html, pdf, notmuch

I have just started using notmuch for email. I was wondering if there is some way I can view the HTML part of an email in an external browser or rendered to a pdf and viewed inside Emacs (like you can do with mu4e)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `notmuch-show-view-part` (bound to `.-v` by default) while point is in the `text/html` part to accomplish this.

For this to function properly you'll need to make sure your `~/.mailcap` file has settings for `text/html`.

Here's what I have in mine on my Mac:

```
text/html; open %s; nametemplate=%s.html
```

Each line is `;` delimited with the first field specifying the content type, the second field specifying the command to use, and any additional fields specifying options.

So I have `nametemplate` which essentially adds `.html` to the filename that `notmuch` generates, which is then passed to `open` (which knows how to handle it because of the `.html` ending).

The format is described in [RFC 1524](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1524.html).

---

As mentioned, you need to be in the `text/hmtl` part of the email for this to work.   Since this can be inconvenient, I use this function which you can call from anywhere in the message in order to open the html part:

```lisp
(defun notmuch-show-view-html+ ()
  "Open the text/html part of the current message using
`notmuch-show-view-part'."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char
     (prop-match-beginning
      (text-property-search-forward
       :notmuch-part
       "text/html"
       (lambda (value notmuch-part)
         (equal (plist-get notmuch-part :content-type)
                value)))))
    (notmuch-show-view-part)))
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured out the mailcap part but your explanation helps! I have set up to view the email in the browser and I am now trying to add a second option to convert the HTML to a PDF file. I have not started figuring this yet but your answer gives me very good directions. Thanks!

Comment: Great answer. Do you know if `notmuch-show-view-part` can also export inline images, or will they always be missing?